# Opening files with default Windows application from within emacs

Tags: windows, emacs, elisp

I'm trying to tweak the `dired-find-file` function in emacs on Windows XP so that when I open (say) a pdf file from dired it fires up a copy of Acrobat Reader and opens that file with it, instead of opening it within emacs. But I can't work out what variant on `shell-command/call-process` to use. Here's what I have so far:

```
(defadvice dired-find-file (around dired-find-file-external (filename &optional wildcards))
  "Open non-text files with an appropriate external program."
  (if (string= ".pdf" (substring filename (- (length filename) 4))) ; obviously I'll replace this with something more general/robust
    (shell-command filename) ;; what should go here?
    (ad-do-it)))

(ad-activate 'dired-find-file)
```

I know I could hard-code it to start Acrobat Reader by giving it the location of the .exe file. But I'd rather have something which requires less searching from me and which won't break when default applications move/change. What should I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Evaluate the following elisp
2. Run dired (M-x dired)
3. Browse to directory and file
4. With point on file, pressing F3 will open the file based on the windows extension.

   `(defun w32-browser (doc) (w32-shell-execute 1 doc))`

   `(eval-after-load "dired" '(define-key dired-mode-map [f3] (lambda () (interactive) (w32-browser (dired-replace-in-string "/" "\\" (dired-get-filename))))))`

Comment: Not keen on eval-after-load, but +1 for w32-shell-execute - it's clearly the Right Way To Do It.

Comment: Whye it says `Defining kbd macro...` when I press ``F3`

Answer (score 9):

To extend on the 'org-open-file' proposal:

```
(defun my-dired-find-file (&optional prefix)
    (interactive "P")
    (if prefix
        (org-open-file (dired-get-file-for-visit) 'system)
      (dired-find-file)))

(define-key dired-mode-map "\r" 'my-dired-find-file)
```

Will let you open a file externally with `C-u RET'.

found at http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2012-11/msg01069.html

Answer (score 4):

Use [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/DiredPlus#w32-browser) for this, along with [`w32-browser.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/w32-browser.el)

- <kbd>C-RET</kbd> opens the current-line's file using its Windows file-association application.
- <kbd>M-RET</kbd> opens Windows Explorer to the file or folder
- <kbd>^</kbd>, when in a root directory (e.g. `C:\`), moves up to a Dired-like list of all Windows drives (local and remote).

The commands for the first two are available from `w32-browser.el`. (Dired+ binds them to those keys.) The command for the third is from Dired+.

Comment: But the minibuffer says `the M-Ret is not defined`

Comment: @ZhaoGang: Thanks. Corrected. Forgot that the first two commands are defined in w32-browser.el.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this terrific web page](http://systeminetwork.com/article/calling-windows-shellexec-cl) via google, which let me to a technique using RunDll that works. I'm putting it up here in case anyone else is curious.

Here is the key piece of code, which opens `filename` using the appropriate application:

```
(shell-command (concat "rundll32 shell32,ShellExec_RunDLL " (shell-quote-argument filename)))
```

And here is my full solution. (Note that `dired-find-file` is just a wrapper round `find-file` which doesn't know the filename, so that you have to advise `find-file` rather than `dired-find-file` as in the question. If you don't want the behaviour for `find-file` you will probably need to rewrite `dired-find-file` or write more complicated advice.)

```
(defun open-externally (filename)
  (shell-command (concat "rundll32 shell32,ShellExec_RunDLL " (shell-quote-argument filename))))

(defun is-file-type? (filename type)
  (string= type (substring filename (- (length filename) (length type)))))

(defun should-open-externally? (filename)
  (let ((file-types '(".pdf" ".doc" ".xls")))
    (member t (mapcar #'(lambda (type) (is-file-type? filename type)) file-types))))

(defadvice find-file (around find-file-external-file-advice (filename &optional wildcards))
  "Open non-emacs files with an appropriate external program"
  (if (should-open-externally? filename)
      (open-externally filename)
    ad-do-it))

(ad-activate 'find-file)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have this in my .emacs:

```
(setq dired-guess-shell-alist-user
  (list
    (list "\\.*$" "cmd /k")
  ))
```

This will open the file using cmd.exe which will use whatever program is associated with the file extension. Tested to work on Windows 8 and GNU Emacs 24.2.1.

Comment: I'm testing `(setq dired-guess-shell-alist-user '((".*" (concat "start " "\"" file "\""))))` at the moment. (I encountered filenames with spaces.)

Answer (score 1):

Tom Smith's answer is nice, but you can also just run the program "start" with the filename as an argument.

```
(shell-command (concat "start " (shell-quote-argument filename)))
```

Comment: Are you sure? When I've tried this it doesn't work - I just get an empty command prompt window.

Comment: @Tom: That makes sense, since the first quoted argument to `start` is used as the window title.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `(w32-shell-execute "open" file-name)`.

In fact, in my init file I have:

```
(defun open-externally (file-name)
  (interactive "fOpen externally: ")
  (let ((process-connection-type nil))
     (start-process "open-externally" nil
                    "xdg-open" file-name)))

(when (eq window-system 'w32)
  (defun open-externally (file-name)
    (interactive "fOpen externally: ")
    (w32-shell-execute "open" file-name)))
```

Which defines a command that (may be used interactively and) opens a file with the default application according to `xdg-open` and then, if I'm actually on Windows, redefines that command appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

`org-open-file` is  a system independent external opener. See `org-file-apps` for how to customize it further.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @tom-smith's answer, here is something that I validated and just works on Windows (inspired from @Tom-smith and [xahlee blogpost](http://xahlee.info/emacs/misc/elisp_calling_windows_cmd.html).

Add this snippet to your `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```lsp
;;; Open file types with default Windows apps
;;; -------------------------------------------------------------------
(defun open-externally (filename)
  (shell-command (format "%s" (shell-quote-argument filename))))

(defun is-file-type? (filename type)
  (string= type (substring filename (- (length filename) (length type)))))

;; => change this to include more file types <=
(defun should-open-externally? (filename)
  (let ((file-types '(".pdf" ".doc" ".xls" ".html")))
    (member t (mapcar #'(lambda (type) (is-file-type? filename type)) file-types))))

(defadvice find-file (around find-file-external-file-advice (filename &optional wildcards))
  "Open non-emacs files with an appropriate external program"
   (if (should-open-externally? filename)
      (open-externally filename)
     ad-do-it))

(ad-activate 'find-file)
;;; -------------------------------------------------------------------
```