# Make Emacs dired run program according to Windows registry

Tags: emacs, dired

When I use Emacs dired, it opens all the files inside emacs. How to make it execute .exe files, open pdf in pdf viewer, etc.

So it can't be a replacement to Windows explorer and total commander.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284319/opening-files-with-default-windows-application-from-within-emacs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use 'dired' myself, but [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html) suggests you can run shell commands on the files.

The [reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell-Commands-in-Dired.html#Shell-Commands-in-Dired) mentions using & or ! followed by the shell commands to perform the command on one or more files.

Answer (score 4):

Use ! followed by shell command:

cmd /c start ""

Comment: It looks like in some cases `start ""` also works. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Start dired, if not done already, press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>.
Select the file you want to run, just navigate to it using <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>/<kbd>p</kbd>.
Press & <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
Hopefully your selected file should run in async mode.